# Conditional Probability with 6 dice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

Consider that a fair dice is thrown 6 times. I want to compute the probability that to have exactly two 6s "given" that we have exactly 2 5s. So I use the conditional probability equation:
\begin{equation}\mathbb{P}(\text{two } 6s|\text{two }5s)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{two } 6s\cap\text{two }5s)}{\mathbb{P}(\text{two }5s)}\end{equation}
So the probability of throwing exactly two 5s from 6 throws is given by $15\times(\frac{1}{6})^{2}(\frac{5}{6})^{4}$, where the 15 comes from the 15 possible combinations to get exactly 2 5s. Now comes the part where I am stuck. Looking at the numerator, more precisly the intersection, I don't see what the intersection of the two events would be. Throwing 2 6s and 2 5s would be the union I believe. Is the intersection to throw 4 of 1,2,3 and 4? From that I believe I would also need to determine the number of combinations that we have this. Someone who knows how to compute my numerator?

Comment: Since you have exactly two $5's$ there are four unknown faces, none of which can be $5$.  Each of these has a $\frac 15$ chance of being a $6$.

Comment: If you want to do it your way:  There are two ways to place the $6's$ then two ways to place the $5's$ and then a $\left(\frac 16\right)^4$ chance that you gets $6's$ and $5's$ in those locations, and a $\left(\frac 46\right)^2$ chance that the other two rolls are neither $6$ nor $5$.  It's not a bad exercise to confirm that this computation gives the same result as the (simpler) method I described.

Comment: Thanks @lulu! I used both methods you described and got the result $\frac{96}{625}$ for both.